# Copy and transfer only the maximum values of data from one column to another in the field calculator

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, field-calculator

In the Attribute Table there is a field with the diameter and width of the pipe. I want to transfer all the data from this field to a new field. While in one line there can be several values of the diameter and width as shown in the screenshot, I need only transfer the maximum diameter, in the field calculator.

[image]

For example - in the screenshot, move to the new field only the maximum values of 1020 * 10.5 in the new field,  And the values of 720 * 11 should not be transferred to a new field.
[image]

Comment: I see both `;` and `:` as delimiters: is it a typo?

Comment: A few doubts - Do you want to copy the diameter-width pair value based on the maximum value of diameter only or the evaluation of expression `1020*10.5`? Also there seems to be some inconsistency of the data in the column - like `108x6`,`1020*10.5: 720*11` and `530*8-12`; with the separators being different `x`,`*`,`:`,`-`. Is it a typo or the data is like that?

Comment: There is no typo, all tabulation such as:; I will then replace

Comment: * It is a separator between a diameter and a width, as for example 100x100 it is needed

Comment: @zhora Thanks, I got it. Please, see if my answer solves your issue (It should consider all the tabulations you provided as an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may run the following code from the **Python Console**, remembering to preliminary edit the name of the fields of interest (see the comments in the code below):

```py
from qgis.core import *

layer = iface.activeLayer()
field = 'test' # replace this with the name of your starting field
newfield = 'result' # replace this with the name of your new field

layer.startEditing()
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    string = feat[field]
    if string:
        tmp_dict = {}
        repl1=string.replace(' ', '')
        repl2=repl1.replace(':', ';')
        fields = repl2.split(';')
        max_value = 0
        for fd in fields:
            splitted = fd.split('*')
            if not splitted[0].isdigit():
                splitted = fd.split('x')
            if float(splitted[0]) > max_value:
                max_value = float(splitted[0])
                attribute = fd
        feat[newfield] = attribute
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
layer.commitChanges()
```

I tested it on this Attribute Table:

[image]

and this is the result I have obtained:

[image]

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function editor in the Field Calculator to define a function for your task. Assuming the diameter-width pairs are separated by `;` and `*` is the separator between diameter and width, the following function **select_maxdiam** defined in the *Function Editor* should work -

```
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def select_maxdiam(value1, feature, parent):
    #Removing all the space characters 
    newval = value1.replace(' ','')
    #Splitting the diameter-width pairs
    newval = newval.split(';')
    maxval = 0
    fin = ''
    for i in newval:
        a = i.split('*')[0]
        if float(a)>maxval:
            maxval = float(a)
            fin = i
    return fin
```

Here `a` contains the value of the diameter part of each pair which is compared with the rest to find the maximum among them.
In the expression tab you can just type `select_maxdiam("dimensions")`, where `dimensions` should be replaced by your column name containing the data.

Following screenshots are for reference -

Function editor
[image: Function editor]

Field Calculator
[image: Field calculator]

Result looks like this - [image]